# Determine if azure blob storage path is a prefix or points to a blob item

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Using this endpoint /files/azurepath/properties to get the properties of an individual blob item. Now, I would like to use the same endpoint, pass the azure "folder" prefix, retrieve properties of all the blob items with the prefix, and respond as a list of properties object.

Is there a way to check if the provided azurepath is a full path to a blob item or it is a prefix?
Or is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
@get('/files/{azurePath}/properties', {
    responses: {
        '200': {
            description: 'Properties Retrieval Success',
        },
    },
}) 
async getProperties(
    @param.path.string('azurePath') azurePath: string,
    @inject(ML1Bindings.STORAGE_CONTAINER) container: string,
): Promise<FileProperties> {
    const decodedAzurePath: string = decodeURIComponent(azurePath);

    const blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
        this.azureStorageConnectionString,
    );
    const containerClient: ContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
    const blockBlobClient: BlockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(decodedAzurePath);

    let blobProperties: BlobGetPropertiesResponse;
    try {
        blobProperties = await blockBlobClient.getProperties();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.statusCode === 404) {
            throw new HttpErrors.NotFound('The specified file does not exist');
        }

        throw error;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if the provided azurepath is a full path to a
> blob item or it is a prefix? Or is there any other way to accomplish
> what I am trying to do?

Interesting question! Here's one way you can solve this problem.

What you will need to do is perform list blobs operation on the blob container with `{azurePath}` as `blob prefix`.

If this `{azurePath}` is a blob, the result will be a list with a single blob (same name as your azurePath). However if it is a virtual folder, then you will get a list of blobs inside that virtual folder.

In both cases you will get a list of blobs back. You can then iterate over that list and fetch the properties of each blob in that list and return those.

Comment: In case of prefix (virtual folder), I needed to append a "/" to get the list of blobitems, whereas in case of a blobitem, I should not have a "/". I am trying to resolve this...

Comment: It would actually depend on how the virtual folders and blobs are named. If they're named very differently, then you would not need to append "/".

Comment: example: 
1. To get the blobitem: <URL>/files/root%2Fcategory%2Fid%2Fsummarydata.docx/properties 
2. To get all the blobs:: <URL>/files/root%2Fcategory%2Fid%2F/properties

This is in code:

1. containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy('/', {prefix: decodedAzureFolderPrefixPath, includeMetadata: true})
2. containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy('/', {prefix: decodedAzureFolderPrefixPath + "/",  includeMetadata: true})

Comment: In this particular scenario, you don't need to append "/". Blob prefix is essentially the starting letters of a blob name. With `root/category/id` blob prefix, you will be able to find all blobs names of which start with that only. If you had a blob say `root/category/id.txt` then you would run into problems with this approach.

Comment: any suggestions on naming so this is not necessary. we have this folder hierarchy /root/category1/id/
All the blob items that belong to the category and the id, goes under this virtual folder.
A single blob item would then be at
/root/category1/id/blob-item1

Comment: As long as you don't have blobs at the same level as `id` (e.g. `/root/category1/id-blob-item1`), I believe you will be fine. You have to ensure that when your blob prefix is set as `/root/category1/id`, you list blobs inside `id` folder and for that the blob naming will become important. Do give it a try. It should work.